# Is Docker like Virtualbox?

Tags: docker

So I'm new with Docker title and after reading some info about it now I have a thing in my mind. please help me understand it better. Is Docker like Virtual OS services like Virtualbox app? But it can only simulate with my Linux base! Am right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Docker is a management tool; not a virtual machine.

From https://www.docker.com/resources/what-container#/package_software

> **CONTAINERS**
>
> Containers are an abstraction at the app layer that packages code and dependencies together. Multiple containers can run on the same machine and share the OS kernel with other containers, each running as isolated processes in user space. Containers take up less space than VMs (container images are typically tens of MBs in size), can handle more applications and require fewer VMs and Operating systems.

[image]

versus

> **VIRTUAL MACHINES**
>
> Virtual machines (VMs) are an abstraction of physical hardware turning one server into many servers. The hypervisor allows multiple VMs to run on a single machine. Each VM includes a full copy of an operating system, the application, necessary binaries and libraries - taking up tens of GBs. VMs can also be slow to boot.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

**VirtualBox** is a virtualization hypervisor, responsible for providing isolation of hardware resources to guest systems, allowing multiple operating systems to run at the same time on a single computer or server. It provides virtual hardware resources and devices to each operating system, such as processor, memory and network card. Each guest system is composed by an operating system, applications and libraries, exactly as the ones you would install in a computer or server.

**Docker** is a containerization platform which is responsible for providing isolation of software resources, allowing multiple applications to run in isolation at the same time on a single host system without the overhead of running multiple operating systems. It provides isolation of software resources to each container, such as independent users, processes trees and mount points, by using [namespaces](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/overview/#namespaces). Each container is composed
by applications and libraries and share the host system kernel.

[image]

Comment: Just complementing, there is a common thought of "containerization being better than virtualization, since there is less overhead". It may be true when the purpose is running applications in isolation but keep in mind that when a full operating system is needed, virtualization may be the solution. They solve the isolation problem by using different approaches, one by providing isolated hardware resources, one by providing isolated operating system resources.

Answer (score 4):

Docker is a container manager
Virtualbox is a VM manager

so there are fundamental differences between these two

differences between containers (like docker) and VMs are explained here
https://geekflare.com/docker-vs-virtual-machine/

summary:
What’s the Diff: VMs vs Containers

| VMs | Containers |
| --- | --- |
| Heavyweight | Lightweight |
| Limited performance | Native performance |
| Each VM runs in its own OS | All containers share the host OS |
| Hardware-level virtualization | OS virtualization |
| Startup time in minutes | Startup time in milliseconds |
| Allocates required memory | Requires less memory space |
| Fully isolated and hence more secure | Process-level isolation, possibly less secure |